# Why is mapreduce not Executed for Hive queries?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I had one query where we have Hive table created and when we `select * from table  where=< condition>;` ,it gives results immediately without invoking MR job.When I create a same duplicate table and try to execute a query then MR is invoked. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Have you inserted more data in the duplicate table?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337451/regarding-the-hive-commands-that-do-not-invoke-underlying-mapreduce-jobs

Answer (score 1):

Local mode (hive not invoking MR) depends on several conditions (see [HIVE-1408](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1408)):

1. [`hive.exec.mode.local.auto=true/false`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties#ConfigurationProperties-hive.exec.mode.local.auto) - Lets Hive determine whether to run in local mode automatically.
2. `hive.exec.mode.local.auto.input.size.max=1G` - When `hive.exec.mode.local.auto` is true, input bytes should be less than this for local mode.
3. `hive.exec.mode.local.auto.input.files.max=4` - When `hive.exec.mode.local.auto` is true, the number of tasks should be less than this for local mode.

If the tables have the same data, my guess is that there is a difference in the number of tasks that are spawned when querying the two tables causing one query to run in local mode and another to spawn a MR job.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer,The reason was Hive analyze command was issued on the table .Once you execute a hive analyze command it stores number of row,file size in hive metastore.So ,when u do select count(*) from table.It directly fetches it from the hive metastore instead of invoking a map reduce job.
You can also issue a Analyze command on column as well.

```
ANALYZE TABLE [db_name.]tablename [PARTITION(partcol1[=val1], partcol2[=val2], ...)]  -- (Note: Fully support qualified table name since Hive 1.2.0, see HIVE-10007.)
  COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  [FOR COLUMNS]          -- (Note: Hive 0.10.0 and later.)
  [CACHE METADATA]       -- (Note: Hive 2.1.0 and later.)
  [NOSCAN];
```

Documentation link :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev